# NLog does not create log files on ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I am new to using NLog with ASP.NET Core, so I have followed the guide here:
https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json)

I have created the following `nlog.config` file at the root of the project directory:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>


  <!-- define various log targets -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${basedir}\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
                 layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />


    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="${basedir}\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
             layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|  ${message} ${exception}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Inside a controller, I call a line like this one:

`_logger.LogInformation("Entered CustomerRange method");`

which returns the following in the output window in Visual Studio:

`CustomerMgmtAPI.Controllers.CustomerController:Information: Entered CustomerRange method`

However, the actual log files are never created by NLog. I was wondering if someone can point out the error in the NLog configuration here, since I have been reviewing the documentation of NLog for ASP.NET Core project and I can't find the error myself.

Comment: Please check the internal log https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: @Julian I added the following line, but there is no internal log file created in the folder: `internalLogFile="C:\Users\User\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AzureTableStorageShard\CustomerMgmtAPI\internal-nlog.txt"`

Comment: Then probably it can't find you .config file. Is it in you root directory?

Answer (score 2):

So the actual fix to the problem was the remove the first line from the `nlog.config` file:

`﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

I remove this line and everything started working as expected. I also noticed that Visual Studio was giving me these errors when that line was present:

```
Invalid token 'Text' at root level of document.
Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.
```

It seems in this case that the NLog tutorial is broken, as I just took over this file from the sample for ASP.NET Core. I am using VS2017, so perhaps there is an incompatibility with this version of VS?

Comment: that's odd as all my nlog.config files has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`. Maybe there was a (invisible) character before the `<`?

Answer (score 0):

The dirty little secret about using NLog with ASP.NET Core is that you can configure and create logs just as you did in ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.  You just use the regular NLog Nuget package like you normally would.

Just create an NLog.config in your root, etc.  You don't even have to make any extra configurations in the config or elsewhere to get it to work.  You just reference NLog in your class and then create a logger with the LogManager.

What this means is that you don't have all of the wireup in Program.cs etc.